# Nested for loop not working?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def remove_duplicates (user_input):
    black_list = []
    new_list = []
    for i in user_input:
        for t in black_list:
            if i == t:
                break
            else:
                new_list.append(i)
                black_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

I've been taking classes from codecademy and I tried to tackle a problem this way but the second loop doesn't seem to be executing and I've check via print statements throughout the loops but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

black_list is declared empty, [].  Therefore the 2nd for-loop will execute 0 iterations.